# Can a Java Card applet "auto select" itself?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform, device-emulation

If I write a Java Card applet that emulates one or more protocols of the same ISO standard, is there a way to have the applet "auto selected" by protocols which don't use select, or don't know what to select? Because otherwise I'm not going to bother spending ten to twenty dollars for a test device, and god knows I'd need more than one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better looked through [Global Platform specification](http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp) first.
When you install your applet, you can set it as the defaultselect applet.
Two ways to do this.

1- Recommend that you download [JCIDE](http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=43)-- a  **Free** java card applet development. 
 [Here](http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=62) is how to set the defaultselect applet by a simple operation .

2- There is also a handy tool that can meet your need.
You can download it from [here](http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=38)

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install your applet as "default selected", which is basicaly what you want.

Have a look at Global Platform specification, especially parameters of `INSTALL [for install]` command. There is one flag in applet privileges you have to set.

If you work with Eclipse JCOP Tools, you will easily set the flag using GUI Applet Install Properties:

[image]

Comment: In addition keep in mind that you need to set the correct card life cycle state (via the `SET STATUS` command) as this privilege works only in OP_SECURED. In OP_READY and OP_INITIALIZED the ISD is the default selected application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
Javacard Applets are usually always deployed on a smartcard with the underlying Global Platform standard. Global Platform is used to deploy, maintain and manage JavaCard applets. When installing a Java Card applet you can set an option/ flag called `defaultselect`. Only one applet can have the default selected option. Whenever an ATR/ATS is received the JCRE internally selects the applet with default-select option. Any APDUs incoming are directly handed to the applet unless a `select` APDU selects another applet registered in the JCRE.

Comment: In addition keep in mind that you need to set the correct card life cycle state (via the `SET STATUS` command) as this privilege works only in OP_SECURED. In OP_READY and OP_INITIALIZED the ISD is the default selected application.

Comment: definitly not the case on jcop cards

Comment: Interesting. This behavior is specified in global platform v2.1.1/v2.2 (see chapter 5). For OP_READY in v2.0.1 it is stated that "Card Manager acts as the selected application" (section 5.1.1.1). I would not write that If it didn't cause me some trouble in the past :)